# VB Script to Find and Replace text in Word Document

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I don't have too much experience with VB Scripting but I'm trying to write something that will search for a specific string in a word document, replace it with whatever I specify and then print it out on a label printer.

It does the first replacement just fine, but not the second. Could anyone have a look and see what I might be doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Dim WordApp
Dim WordDoc
Dim strReadCompName
Dim strReadCompSN

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = TRUE

WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\LabelTemplate.doc")
WordApp.Documents("LabelTemplate.doc").Activate

Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument

strReadCompName = InputBox("Enter Computer Name", "Name")
strReadCompSN = InputBox("Enter Serial Number", "Serial")

With WordApp.Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .MatchWholeWord = TRUE
    .Text = "nametext"
    .Execute ,,,,,,,,,strReadCompName
End With

With WordApp.Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .MatchWholeWord = TRUE
    .Text = "serialtext"
    .Execute ,,,,,,,,,strReadCompSN
End With

WordDoc.PrintOut()
WordDoc.Saved = TRUE
WordApp.Quit
```

Comment: Not to familiar with script but in VB you can group replacement commands together. I had the same problem and when grouped it fixed the problem. Maybe add them both to the same With, End With Block

Comment: does `"serialtext"` come after `"nametext"` in the document? It might be that the search is starting from the last match. Also when a find is successful doesn't Word select the found text? If so, the second search may only be searching within the selected text and not the whole document.

Comment: Yes, it does come after "nametext." And if that's the case, how would I "un-highlight" the text and set my cursor back to the beginning of the file so I could search from there again?

Comment: @harper89, I tried to group them into the same With statement, but that didn't work either. It's still not finding/replacing "serialtext"

Comment: Solved my own problem. oracle certified professional was right. I just added WordApp.Selection.GoTo 1 to the beginning of a Sub statement. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @d2jxp: Please post your answer as an answer, and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved my own problem haha

Oracle Certified Professional was right. All I had to do was add another statement to move the cursor back to the beginning. I just added WordApp.Selection.GoTo 1 to the beginning.

```
Option Explicit
'Procedure to edit word document add name and serial number. 
Sub SearchAndRep(searchTerm, replaceTerm, WordApp)
    WordApp.Selection.GoTo 1
    With WordApp.Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Text = searchTerm
        .Execute ,,,,,,,,,replaceTerm
    End With
End Sub

Dim WordApp
Dim WordDoc
Dim strReadCompName
Dim strReadCompSN
Dim objNetwork, WSHPrinters, counter

'Enumerate through printers to find local Zebra printer.
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set WSHPrinters = objNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

For counter = 0 To WSHPrinters.Count - 1 Step 2
    If Left(WSHPrinters.Item(counter +1), 5) = "Zebra" Then
        WScript.Echo(WSHPrinters.Item(counter +1))
        objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(WSHPrinters.Item(counter +1))
    End If
Next

'Create a Microsoft Word Object and make it invisible. 
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = FALSE

'Open LabelTemplate.doc for editing. 
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\LabelTemplate.doc")

'Read in name and serial number to print on label. 
strReadCompName = InputBox("Enter Computer Name", "Name")
strReadCompSN = InputBox("Enter Serial Number", "Serial")

'Procedures to edit the Word Document to add name and serial number. 
SearchAndRep "nametext", strReadCompName, WordApp
SearchAndRep "serialtext", strReadCompSN, WordApp

'Print out the label. 
'WordApp.PrintOut()

'Set the default printer back to what it was before. 
'Still have to do this. 
objPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter "\\******\**********"
WordDoc.Saved = TRUE
WordDoc.Close
WordApp.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but I've working on it these days. My VBS function takes 3 arguments: word document full path(string), text values to find(array), text values to replace(array)

```
Function GENERIC_TEXT_REPLACE(path,find_text,replace_text)
' Generic function to replace text in word document
' path(String): Full path of word document
' find_text(Array): Array of values to look For
' replace_text(Array): Array of values to replace

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(path)
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

For  i = 0 to UBound(find_text)
    FindText = find_text(i)
    MatchCase = False
    MatchWholeWord = true
    MatchWildcards = False
    MatchSoundsLike = False
    MatchAllWordForms = False
    Forward = True
    Wrap = wdFindContinue
    Format = False
    wdReplaceNone = 0
    ReplaceWith = replace_text(i)
    wdFindContinue = 1
    wdReaplaceAll = 2

    a = objSelection.Find.Execute(FindText,MatchCase,MatchWholeWord,MatchWildcards,MatchSoundsLike,MatchAllWordForms,Forward,Wrap,Format,ReplaceWith,wdReaplaceAll)
Next

'Save the doc
objDoc.Save
objDoc.Close
objWord.Quit

GENERIC_TEXT_REPLACE = "Success"

End Function
```